# Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string' in typescript

Tags: typescript

When I set following function,

```
const getIrohaTransaction:string = () =>{
    return "test";
}
```

following errors are alerted.

`Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.`
I still couldn't understand the root cause of this error. What is the wrong point of this?If someone has opinion,please let me know. thanks

Comment: A function returning a string is not itself a string, no - that's not really a matter of opinion! Either the type of `getIrohaTransaction` needs to change entirely, or you need to move the `: string` to the return position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty input param is missing in your type definition:

```
const getIrohaTransaction: () => string = () =>{
    return "test";
}
```

In your case the `getIrohaTransaction` variable is defined as `string` whereas it should be marked as `() => string` which means a function that takes no arguments and returns a string.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=28#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygSQE4gBYEMAqquRbBQCW4AXDABQCUMAvAHwzSolhwPV1MDeAsACgYImKiQBXVGBgAiKAmiyA3EIC%20QA)